# How to update sqlite db file after deployment the app in windows phone store

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-store

I have deployed the 1st version of my wp8 in wp store and now i want to deploy the update version of it. Though I know the process of update deployment, but my concern is the sqlite file which doesn't get updated.

Here is the scenario, I have sqlite file in the app where user can store config and setting, in new version I added extra tables and I want to these tables should be reflected in the the update without affecting user settings and config.

What points I should consider to take care of this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Thereis no way to update only sqite db file in store. you have to update hole application.

Comment: I am updating whole application, but the sqlite file is not updated.

Comment: Are you sure. Create a new xap file with new sqlite file. And test before deployement and see changes.

Comment: I did the same with wp power tool, it's the same and not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data in the sqlite database is static you can give the database a new name and submit it with the updated app.  One first run copy the new database to isolated storage and delete the old version of the database to save space.

If the user is inputting data into the database you will have to include code to modify the database structure on the first run and insert any records into the new table

Comment: Thanks, I already performed what you mentioned and I thought this could be the only way out.